# Android Studio error: cannot find symbol class AdapterViewCompat with compileSdkVersion 23 and buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

This is my gradle file and I am getting 
error:

```
cannot find symbol
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
error:package AdapterViewCompat does not exist.
```

Grade is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

 ...    

 dependencies 
 {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:+'
    ...        
  }
```

Comment: Don't add the same dependency twice or more (ex: com.android.support:appcompat-v7) and use the same version for all support libraries:23.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because the

```
android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
```

**doesn't exist** in appcompat v23 (while it existed in v22).
You can check it in

```
androidsdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\appcompat-v7-23.1.0-sources.jar
```

In general don't use the class inside the internal package.

Answer (score 2):

> android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;

**Edit**

You should use `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"` because of Its obsolete in **23** .

Comment: @TarunKundhiya Okay .After change did you clean and restart and Sync (gradle) your project ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330816/error-package-android-support-v7-app-does-not-exist?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: it is a compilation error. It means that either there is a problem in your Java source code, or there is a problem in the way that you are compiling it.

Comment: @TarunKundhiya Updated this answer .

Answer (score 0):

if you have existing code then change AdapterViewCompat to AdapterView and import android.widget.AdapterView;
if you are writing new code then use AdapterView instead AdapterViewcompact as AdapterViewCompact deprecated in api v23 or higher