# Error:(8, 42) error: cannot find symbol class AdapterViewCompat

Tags: android

My compiledSdk version is 23 and targetsdkversion is 23 and I am getting this error cannot find symbol class AdapterViewCompat can anyone help ?
 My compiledSdk version is 23 and targetsdkversion is 23 and I am getting this error cannot find symbol class AdapterViewCompat can anyone help ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3.1'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        // replace with the current version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()

}
dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-android-support:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    compile files('libs/CleverTapSDKValidator-20151217.jar')
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vedicrishiastro.kundli"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 6
        versionName "Beta 1.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

/*apt {
    arguments {
        //androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

        // If you're using flavors you should use the following line instead of hard-coded packageName
         resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}*/

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:2.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4'

    compile project(':multilevelexpindlistview')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'


}
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}


apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609120/android-studio-error-cannot-find-symbol-class-adapterviewcompat-with-compilesdk

Comment: android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
doesn't exist in appcompat v23 (while it existed in v22).
You can check it in

Comment: @sasikumar i saw that but i don't understand what's the solution

Comment: @sasikumar can you tell me solution ?

Comment: change version 22 because version 23 not have appcompat

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609120/android-studio-error-cannot-find-symbol-class-adapterviewcompat-with-compilesdk

Answer (score 0):

```
cannot find symbol class AdapterViewCompat
```

> android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;

**AdapterViewCompat** Doesn't exist in **Appcompat 23 Level** . You should use 22.

```
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if you have existing code then  change AdapterViewCompat to
   AdapterView and  import android.widget.AdapterView;
2. if you are
   writing new code then  use AdapterView instead AdapterViewcompact as
   AdapterViewCompact deprecated in api v23 or higher