# Android WebView Package R not found/Package android.support.v7.app

Tags: java, android, xml, github, gist

I am attempting to making a webview application and I am running into a an error where Android studio cannot find 2 pacakages. Here is the following guide I was sing to complete this: "https://www.wptorc.com/convert-wordpress-site-android-app-using-android-studio/"

Here is the error I receive:
Package R doesn't exist.
package android.support.v7.app

Here is my code in the following gists:

Main Activity - https://gist.github.com/MCMXCIII/b1fa1a2d78d6390a5929b57224d5885d

AndroidManifest.xml - https://gist.github.com/MCMXCIII/2d214230d8e1e28f646def8853c24176

main_activity.xml - https://gist.github.com/MCMXCIII/91d8e2b4a13d5347411e25de3788e0a1

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Edit: I am new to this site and started doing some research on this and I found that I should be importing the following:android.support.v7.app however based on the question I do not have the option to import based on this question.

Tagging the question for reference:[Error "package android.support.v7.app does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330816/error-package-android-support-v7-app-does-not-exist)

2nd Edit: Disregard I found a new tutorial that gave me a better understanding of what is going on.

I am assuming that android studio has since updated since the last tutorial I posted The example that is given in the previous post calls upon two packages that are used differently in the version of android studio in the tutorial.

In the previous tutorial lists R being an extension of the package "appackage" and R is also an extension and in the new version android studio these packages are not called. and just webview is called and used in the new version of android studio.

I am leaving the tutorial that helped me below:
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1gUOTZrMFc"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that android studio has since updated since the last tutorial I posted The example that is given in the previous post calls upon two packages that are used differently in the version of android studio in the tutorial.

In the previous tutorial lists R being an extension of the package "appackage" and R is also an extension and in the new version android studio these packages are not called. and just webview is called and used in the new version of android studio.

I am leaving the tutorial that helped me below: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1gUOTZrMFc"